# The main topics (issues, problems) of the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-analysis

To explain what we are looking for, let's  have a quick review on some points in  Fourier transform on periodic functions  in both  continuous and discrete cases. We emphasize that our attention is just concerned with the abelian groups $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z_n}$ and the unit circle $\textbf{T}$.

On $\textbf{T}$, Fourier transform is a $*$-homomorphism from $L^1(\textbf{T})$ to $c_0(\mathbb{Z})$. One of the main question in this context is characterization of some type of functions for which the inversion formula to be hold (point-wisely and uniformly)  i.e.,
$$f(x)=\sum \hat{f}(n)e^{inx}.$$
Finding the largest space satisfying the inversion formula is still an open problem. On the other hand, outstanding efforts of Kolomogrov, Kahane, Katznelson and Carleson provide  sharp information concerning the points for which the identity $f(x)=\sum \hat{f}(n)e^{inx}$ fails. These two approaches have a long history and are well-organized on some books like *Trigonometric series* written by Zigmond or *Fourier Analysis* by  Duoandikoetxea.

Q. On the abelian groups $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z_n}$, What are the main topics of Fourier transform (references ?)  for anyone who wants to follow.

Comment: You may find Mattila's book interesting from the point of view of your question. https://www.cambridge.org/tr/academic/subjects/mathematics/abstract-analysis/fourier-analysis-and-hausdorff-dimension?format=HB&isbn=9781107107359

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saccone considered the space of all functions on $\mathbb{T}$ with *uniformly convergent* Fourier series. Call this space $U$. There is a natural norm given by $$\|f\|_U = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \|S_nf\|_{L^{\infty}}$$ where $S_nf$ is the $n$th partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$. $U$ is complete with this norm.

It was shown in [[Saccone2000](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-06/S0002-9939-99-05361-7/)] that $U$ is not closed under pointwise multiplication of functions, so it's not a uniform algebra. Also, as a Banach space, $U$ has Pelczynski property (V) and Dunford-Pettis property.

---

Edit/Correction: $(\exists f,g\in U\hspace{4mm} fg\notin U)$ was not shown in [[Saccone2000](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-06/S0002-9939-99-05361-7/)]. Saccone refers to an [article](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=188695) by Kahane & Katznelson in 1965.